# Rational ClearCase installation on Windows

Tags: installation, clearcase

Is there anyone who can help me to download and install Rational Clear Case trial software. I have been spending almost a day to do it. In IBM web page there are tons of links which directs to another page the new pages directing other pages I am ending up with tens of tabs opened my browser but still could not find even installer or download files.

My OS is Win 7 x64 and both Eclipse and Visual Studio integration is acceptable.If had been able to install the software may be I could have installed plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I never downloaded a trial for ClearCase. Everything now uses [PA (Passport Advantage)](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/howtobuy/passportadvantage/pao_customers.htm) in order to download a full product or its patches.

You need an IBM ID in order to access the "Software and services online" page (Access to downloads, account information and commerce)

There, you can click on ["Software download & media access"](https://www-112.ibm.com/software/howtobuy/passportadvantage/paocustomer/sdma/SDMA?P0=DOWNLOAD_OVERVIEW), and then the ["download finder"](https://www-112.ibm.com/software/howtobuy/passportadvantage/paocustomer/sdma/SDMA?P0=DOWNLOAD_FINDER) in order to select ClearCase.

Then an IBM commercial can give you trial licenses to use with that full product.

Comment: I think there is no regular download method for Rational ClearCase since I am able to download [Rational Functional Tester] (http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/functional) ,[Rational Team Concert  ](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/rtc) as they have download links in their product pages.As for ClearCase the same page appearance but download options are missing.

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan that is what I was saying in the answer: for ClearCase, you have to go through PA (Passport Advantage). You won't find a regular download link publicly accessible.